# How to include the pip package in python2.7.14 installation from sources

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, configure

I need to install python2.7.14 from the sources and I'd like to include pip in the installation, how can I accomplish that? I think this will be done via the --with-PACKAGE switch in the configure script. I tried:

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-pip=yes
./configure --enable-shared --with-pip-9.0.1=yes
./configure --enable-shared --with-pip-9.0.1-py2=yes
```

Every time I got an `unrecognized option warning` when I ran either of the above command. So how is it possible to include the pip package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `./configure --help`:

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-ensurepip=upgrade
```

Comment: `--with-ensurepip=install` was the solution for me